# Python script functions correctly except when I try to call it from a bash script

Tags: python, bash

I am creating a bash script, for Mac OS, to run several python scripts in sequence. Right now I am just trying to get the bash script to run one python script and have been unsuccessful.

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /Users/johndoe/Documents/Projects/Test.py
```

I made the bash file executable with chmod 700, and gave the gatekeeper permission to run it. Here is what it says when I run the script:

```
MacBook:~ JohnDoe$ /Users/JohnDoe/Documents/Projects/Bscript ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/Projects/Test.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open('Data/' + filename + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data/20180105-234709.json'
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

This python script works just as intended when running from the terminal manually, but the Bash script gives me an error about the `with open` line. Does anyone have an idea whats going on? It appears that it is failing to create a new file... but why is that causing it to fail if that is the case?

For background the Test.py is pulling Json data from internet and saving it to a new file it creates.

Thank you.

Comment: If you change `'Data/'` to `'./Data/'`, does it work?

Comment: You might just run it from the wrong directory!

Comment: @csabinho is likely correct.

Comment: You could also try an absolute path that you are sure works

Comment: I tired both `./Data/` and using the full file path but neither would fixed the issue. Any suggestions for running a several python scripts in series and not using a bash script?